# How to assign unicode json string

Tags: python, json, unicode, lxml, python-unicode

I'm work with lxml and try to put the parsed data to json string. But my data is unicode string, and it converts automatically.

Here is my code:

```
from lxml import html,etree
import pprint
import requests
url="http://thuvienphapluat.vn"
page = requests.get(url)
tree=html.fromstring(page.content)
vbplm=tree.xpath('//div[@id="VBPLMOI"]//div[@class="left-col"]')
rlst={}
# print etree.tostring(tree.find('./a'),pretty_print=True)
import re
for vb in vbplm:
    id = re.sub(r"\n*\s",'',vb.xpath('.//*[@class="number"]/text()')[0])
    rlst[id]={}
    tmp=vb.xpath('.//a')

    for tpm_part in tmp:
        rlst[id][
                (tpm_part.xpath('.//text()'))[0].encode(encoding='utf-8')
            ]=((tpm_part.get("href")))
        print (tpm_part.xpath('.//text()'))[0].encode(encoding='utf-8')
        print "<<<<<<<<"
        break
    break
pprint.pprint(rlst)
```

Here is my result:

```
Văn bản hợp nhất 02/VBHN-BGDĐT năm 2017 hướng dẫn Quyết định 152/2007/QĐ-TTg về học bổng chính sách đối với học sinh, sinh viên học tại cơ sở giáo dục thuộc hệ thống giáo dục quốc dân do Bộ Giáo dục và Đào tạo ban hành
<<<<<<<<

    {'1': {'V\xc4\x83n b\xe1\xba\xa3n h\xe1\xbb\xa3p nh\xe1\xba\xa5t 02/VBHN-BGD\xc4\x90T n\xc4\x83m 2017 h\xc6\xb0\xe1\xbb\x9bng d\xe1\xba\xabn Quy\xe1\xba\xbft \xc4\x91\xe1\xbb\x8bnh 152/2007/Q\xc4\x90-TTg v\xe1\xbb\x81 h\xe1\xbb\x8dc b\xe1\xbb\x95ng ch\xc3\xadnh s\xc3\xa1ch \xc4\x91\xe1\xbb\x91i v\xe1\xbb\x9bi h\xe1\xbb\x8dc sinh, sinh vi\xc3\xaan h\xe1\xbb\x8dc t\xe1\xba\xa1i c\xc6\xa1 s\xe1\xbb\x9f gi\xc3\xa1o d\xe1\xbb\xa5c thu\xe1\xbb\x99c h\xe1\xbb\x87 th\xe1\xbb\x91ng gi\xc3\xa1o d\xe1\xbb\xa5c qu\xe1\xbb\x91c d\xc3\xa2n do B\xe1\xbb\x99 Gi\xc3\xa1o d\xe1\xbb\xa5c v\xc3\xa0 \xc4\x90\xc3\xa0o t\xe1\xba\xa1o ban h\xc3\xa0nh':
 'http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Giao-duc/Van-ban-hop-nhat-02-VBHN-BGDDT-huong-dan-152-2007-QD-TTg-hoc-bong-chinh-sach-hoc-sinh-sinh-vien-342726.aspx'}}
```

It's not save as format "Văn bản hợp nhất 02/VBHN-BGDĐT năm 2017 hướng dẫn Quyết định 152/2007/QĐ-TTg về học bổng chính sách đối với học sinh, sinh viên học tại cơ sở giáo dục thuộc hệ thống giáo dục quốc dân do Bộ Giáo dục và Đào tạo ban hành".

Please help me create this unicode json string.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  just have a Python dict. You need to use the `json` module to produce a JSON string.

```
import json
print(json.dumps(rlst))
```

Comment: Probably? That's an entirely separate question.